# Chrome switches to serial downloading of scripts

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, script-tag

Sometimes (not every time, but usually) when I'm developing locally, after hundreds of JS files have successfully been downloaded (looks like we currently pull 1393 scripts), Chrome will switch from downloading the files in parallel to downloading them serially.

The server is node, using express and the module "serve-static". I'm using Chrome 43.0. I'm using node 0.12.2. I'm using serve-static 1.9.3. The files are all being requested using a regular script tag like `<script src="foobar.js"></script>`. I suspect this is a Chrome issue because the server responses don't change. But the browser requests don't change either, only their timing/ordering.

Any ideas?

[image]
[image]

Edit: Given that this looks to be a Chrome issue, I have submitted a bug-report to Chromium here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&q=serial%20script%20downloading&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Week%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&id=500948&thanks=500948&ts=1434467876

Comment: And what would you expect? Considering that HTTP specification limits number of simultaneous client/server connections...

Comment: And yet, how exactly you include those scripts?

Comment: @c-smile HTTP spec limits the number of simultaneous connections but they **should** then download in groups, that is 6 conections closed 6 new more opened(or reused) for example. One by one is a strange issue.

Comment: How do you include these scripts? If each of them use for example something like`requirejs(["next"])` then these next[1..N] scripts will be loaded sequentially by nature.

Comment: You should set the community wiki answer as accepted if this was in fact an issue with Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Every browser has a maximum number of concurrent requests it will perform at one time from any given host, and will queue all other requests. The majority of browsers support 6 per hostname. See here for more detail on each browser: http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network&v=top

1393 is a lot of scripts to be downloading on a single page. You may need to review the overall project architecture & file structure to minimize those files to address the root.

You can look into minifying/ compressing your javascript files in a single file or set of files, which should be done even if you only have a few javascript files to optimize performance.

You can also use CDN's (Content Delivery Network) to host some or all of the files. By distributing files across different hostnames (ie http://host1.com/file1.js and http://host2.com/file2.js) the browser can download the max concurrent files from each host at the same time.

Comment: Because of the number of scripts, the staircase effect is expected, but in the screenshot given, after the first 6 it is definitely not loading any scripts in parallel; all of the others are fully processed one at a time.

Comment: In production we concat and minify, this is an issue I'm experiencing in development locally

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a Chrome issue, a [bug-report has been submitted to Chromium here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&q=serial%20script%20downloading&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Week%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&id=500948&thanks=500948&ts=1434467876):